# Ethernet Stop Flashing Lights

Tags: windows, mac, ethernet, modem

Is there a way to prevent flashing lights, or turn off the lights on ethernet cable port/modem? is there a setting on Windows or Macs ? Nothing is wrong, I just have good network activity. I am just annoyed by flashing lights (rare disease). I don't want to use blackout stickers just yet. Is there something in computer settings?

Comment: It really depends on the specific device(s) with the flashing lights on it; some'll have ways to disable the lights, some won't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS settings can only affect Ethernet ports within the computer itself – they cannot control external devices such as cable/DSL modems (those are more of standalone devices than computer peripherals).

For cable/DSL modems, if such an option was present, then it would be available through the modem's own settings page (e.g. the typical `http://192.168.1.1`), but most likely it is *not* present – so you'll have to cover the actual LEDs.

For internal Ethernet ports, I think I've seen one or two Ethernet NIC models that have a driver option to disable LEDs, but most also do not. (You can check via Device Manager to see all settings that the driver supports; sometimes the newer driver available via "optional Windows updates" supports more than the initial one).

Answer (score 2):

In the large majority of cases, these LED lights are controlled by the
hardware of the port and are not under your control.

In some cases this is still possible :

- If the BIOS has an ErP Support (or power economy),
  this determines whether to let the
  system consume less than 1W of power in the S5 (shutdown) state.
  When this setting is enabled, the following four functions will become
  unavailable: PME Event Wake Up, Power On By Mouse, Power On By Keyboard,
  and Wake On LAN. As a by-product, it may also turn off the LED lights
  to conserve power.
- Disabling Wake on LAN both in BIOS and Windows network driver
  sometimes helps to turn off these lights.
- There are stickers called 'Dots' which are designed specifically for
  covering LEDs, but you may also use semi-transparent silicon tape
  to reduce the lights.
- Going to wireless avoids all LEDs.